# Estrutura wide para long - R

Tags: r

Estou a tentar construir um dataset com uma estrutura tipo long, com 2 variáveis within-subject e 2 between-subject de uma tabela do excel.
A estrutura é a seguinte:

```
> str(Subset_0)         
'data.frame':   54 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Subject : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ BETWEEN1: num  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ BETWEEN2: num  1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A_x1    : num  5 1 3 1 0 6 1 2 7 1 ...
 $ B_x2    : num  5 1 3 0 3 0 0 2 6 1 ...
 $ C_y1    : num  6 9 9 2 2 4 2 2 6 0 ...
 $ D_y2    : num  6 15 4 1 2 4 3 1 3 0 ...
 $ K_x1    : num  5 1 3 1 0 6 1 2 7 1 ...
 $ L_x2    : num  5 1 3 0 3 0 0 2 6 1 ...
 $ M_y1    : num  6 9 9 2 2 4 2 2 6 14 ...
 $ N_y2    : num  3 1 0 4 0 5 6 5 17 21 ...
```

data file from `dput`:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55), BETWEEN1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BETWEEN2 = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_x1 = c(5, 
1, 3, 1, 0, 6, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
14, 23, 19, 10, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 8, 24, 17, 8, 22, 14, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), B_x2 = c(5, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
7, 14, 23, 19, 10, 14, 29, 15, 7, 13, 16, 7, 9, 17, 6, 7, 16, 
6, 11, 13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C_y1 = c(6, 9, 9, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 
0, 6, 0, 1, 10, 3, 8, 14, 29, 15, 7, 17, 21, 24, 7, 32, 31, 31, 
21, 27, 29, 18, 27, 33, 23, 28, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), D_y2 = c(6, 15, 
4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 17, 21, 24, 7, 24, 
16, 28, 7, 28, 23, 25, 25, 24, 28, 33, 27, 31, 33, 21, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), K_x1 = c(5, 1, 3, 1, 0, 6, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 
24, 16, 28, 7, 24, 31, 31, 13, 32, 35, 32, 22, 29, 32, 32, 29, 
34, 32, 34, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), L_x2 = c(5, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 6, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 24, 31, 31, 13, 30, 30, 34, 12, 31, 27, 
23, 25, 33, 28, 31, 29, 30, 36, 24, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), M_y1 = c(6, 
9, 9, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 14, 23, 19, 10, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 8, 
24, 17, 8, 22, 14, 33, 28, 31, 14, 23, 19, 10, 9, 10, 11, 14, 
16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), N_y2 = c(3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 5, 17, 21, 24, 7, 
32, 31, 31, 21, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27, 29, 18, 27, NA, NA, 17, 21, 
24, 7, 32, 31, 31, 21, 27, 17, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-54L))
```

Eu preciso de separar por sujeito e por condição. Há duas colunas são variaveis dependentes: Os valores de A, B, C, and D é suposto ficarem numa columana com o nome 'First'; e os valores de K, L, M, N  noutra columan e chama-la 'Second'. Para além disso, o x, y, 1, 2 que estão em indice nestas variaveis no subset original representam  within-subject factors, que também precisam de ser tidos em conta noutras duas colunas: 'Within1'(1,2) e 'Within2'(x,y). Para além disso, preciso também de outras duas colunas com os valores das between-subject variables.

Preciso que fique similar ao seguinte:

```
Subject First  SecondI  Within1  Within2 Between1 Between2
1         Ai     Ki        1      x          1        1 
1         Bi     Li        2      x          1        1 
1         Ci     Mi        1      y          1        1      
1         Di     Ni        2      y          1        1 
2         Ai     Ki        1      x          1        1 
2         Bi     Li        2      x          1        1 
2         Ci     Mi        1      y          1        1 
2         Di     Ni        2      y          1        1 
...
```

Já usei a função `reshape` para agrupar numa só coluna os valores de A,B,C,D e separar os withi-subject values deles e sucedi:

```
Subset_1 <-reshape(Subset_0, 
                   varying = c("A_x1", " B_x2", "C_y1", "D_y2"),
                   v.names = "First",
                   timevar = "Within1",
                   times =  c("A_x1", " B_x2", "C_y1", "D_y2"),
                   direction = "long")

# Next_Trial_Choice column
Subset_1$Within1[Subset_1$Within1== "A_x1"] <- "x"
Subset_1$Within1[Subset_1$Within1== "B_x2"] <- "x"
Subset_1$Within1[Subset_1$Within1== "C_y1"] <- "y"
Subset_1$Within1[Subset_1$Within1== "D_y2"] <- "y"

#cleaning the names - opponent column
Subset_1$Within2[Subset_1$Within2== "A_x1"] <- "1"
Subset_1$Within2[Subset_1$Within2== "B_x2"] <- "2"
Subset_1$Within2[Subset_1$Within2== "C_y1"] <- "1"
Subset_1$Within2[Subset_1$Within2== "D_y2"] <- "2"
```

O problema é que preciso de fazer o mesmo para outra coluna ('Second') e estou a ter dificuldades em usar o reshape outra vez 'em cima' do primeiro reshape.
Há alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução usando `data.table` para criar o novo *data.frame* com os nomes das colunas como variáveis por `Subject` e extraindo as informações necessárias usando expressões regulares:

```
library(data.table)

novo.df <- as.data.table(Subset_0)[,
  .(First = grep("A_|B_|C_|D_", names(Subset_0), value = TRUE),
    Second = grep("K_|L_|M_|N_", names(Subset_0), value = TRUE),
    Between1 = BETWEEN1,
    Between2 = BETWEEN2),
  by = Subject]

novo.df[, `:=`(Within1 = sub("\\D+", "", First),            # remove tudo que não for dígito
               Within2 = sub(".*_(.*)\\d", "\\1", Second),  # mantém entre _ e primeiro dígito
               First = sub("_\\D*", "", First),             # remove tudo que não for dígito depois do _
               Second = sub("_\\D*", "", Second))]          # idem

head(novo.df, 12)
#>     Subject First Second Between1 Between2 Within1 Within2
#>  1:       1    A1     K1        1        1       1       x
#>  2:       1    B2     L2        1        1       2       x
#>  3:       1    C1     M1        1        1       1       y
#>  4:       1    D2     N2        1        1       2       y
#>  5:       2    A1     K1        1        1       1       x
#>  6:       2    B2     L2        1        1       2       x
#>  7:       2    C1     M1        1        1       1       y
#>  8:       2    D2     N2        1        1       2       y
#>  9:       3    A1     K1        1        2       1       x
#> 10:       3    B2     L2        1        2       2       x
#> 11:       3    C1     M1        1        2       1       y
#> 12:       3    D2     N2        1        2       2       y
```

A mesma, com `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

novo.df <- Subset_0 %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(First = grep("A_|B_|C_|D_", names(Subset_0), value = TRUE),
            Second = grep("K_|L_|M_|N_", names(Subset_0), value = TRUE),
            Between1 = BETWEEN1,
            Between2 = BETWEEN2) %>%
  mutate(Within1 = sub("\\D+", "", First),
         Within2 = sub(".*_(.*)\\d", "\\1", Second),
         First = sub("_\\D*", "", First),
         Second = sub("_\\D*", "", Second))
```